# recursive function crawler directories dont detect all folders

Tags: c++, winapi

i am creating a directory crawler to list all directories , sub directories , and files inside them, but somehow some folders was skip from the crawler. I tried to check the code , and if I tried to pass the path as an absolute. I could get the rest of files. basically recursively search through a directory for all sub-directories within any directories of sub-directories

```
bool crawldirs(wstring path, wstring mask, vector<wstring>& files) {
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    wstring spec;
    stack<wstring> directories;

    directories.push(path);
    files.clear();

    while (!directories.empty()) {
        path = directories.top();
        spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();

        hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            return false;
        }

        do {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 &&
                wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
                else {
                    files.push_back(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return true;
}

void crawlDirectories() {
    vector<wstring> files;
    if (crawldirs(L"D:\\", L"*", files)) {
        for (vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin();
            it != files.end();
            ++it) {
            wcout << it->c_str() << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    crawlDirectories();
    return 0;
}
```

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\xxxx\strix\Release>strix.exe
D:\\poc.c
D:\\things.txt
D:\\xxxx\Videos\movies\No Reservations (2007) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]\No.Reservations.2007.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4
D:\\xxxx\Videos\movies\No Reservations (2007) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]\No.Reservations.2007.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM].srt
D:\\xxxx\Music\
```

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\xxxx\strix\Release>D:

D:\>dir
 Volume in drive D is Bk-Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 7AC4-6C0A

 Directory of D:\

06/30/2019  12:30 AM             1,346 poc.c
06/30/2019  12:30 AM               210 things.txt
05/30/2019  04:45 PM    <DIR>          xxxx
               2 File(s)          1,556 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  961,850,376,192 bytes free

D:\>cd xxxx

D:\xxxx>dir
 Volume in drive D is Bk-Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 7AC4-6C0A

 Directory of D:\xxxx

05/30/2019  04:45 PM    <DIR>          .
05/30/2019  04:45 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/27/2019  11:33 PM    <DIR>          Documents
05/22/2019  07:54 AM    <DIR>          Pictures
05/22/2019  12:56 PM    <DIR>          Music
04/25/2019  11:07 PM    <DIR>          Videos
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  961,850,376,192 bytes free
```

Comment: You need a recursive function instead of a while loop.

Comment: If there are no other files in the directory except `.` and `..`, then the directory will not be stored in `vector<wstring> files`.

Comment: Fyi, the moment you run across a folder you haven't access to run FindFirstFile upon, you `return` and thus your entire loop terminates. You should just `continue` , moving on to the next entry in `directories` if any are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine if the current directory is empty, if it is empty, put the directory in the file vector, if not, enter the directory and continue to find.

```
bool crawldirs(wstring path, wstring mask, vector<wstring>& files) {
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    wstring spec;
    stack<wstring> directories;
    directories.push(path);
    files.clear();

    while (!directories.empty()) {
        path = directories.top();
        spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();
        BOOL isEmpty = true;//determine if it's an empty folder.
        hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            return false;
        }

        do {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 &&
                wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
                else {
                    files.push_back(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                    isEmpty = false;//It not an empty folder since it has normal file.
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
        if (isEmpty)
        {
            files.push_back(path);
        }
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or instead the while loop. It's more clearly to use a recursive call to list all directories , sub directories , and files.

```
bool RetrieveFile(TCHAR* szDir)
{
    BOOL isEmpty = true;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
    _tcscat(szDir, _T("\\*"));
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);
    // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return false;
    }
    do
    {
        if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if (!_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName, _T(".")) || !_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName, _T("..")))
                continue;
            TCHAR szDircpy[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
            _tcscpy(szDircpy, szDir);
            szDircpy[_tcslen(szDircpy) - 1] = _T('\0'); // remove "*" character from "xxx\\*"
            _tcscat(szDircpy, ffd.cFileName); //add the subdirectory name into szDir
            RetrieveFile(szDircpy);
        }
        else
        {
            isEmpty = false;
            filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
            filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
            TCHAR szfilepath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
            _tcscpy(szfilepath, szDir);
            szfilepath[_tcslen(szfilepath) - 1] = _T('\0'); // remove "*" character from "xxx\\*"
            _tcscat(szfilepath, ffd.cFileName); //add the subdirectory name into szDir
            _tprintf(TEXT("%s   %ld bytes\n"), szfilepath, filesize.QuadPart);
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    if (isEmpty)
        _tprintf(TEXT("%s   [DIR]\n"), szDir);
    FindClose(hFind);
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH] = _T("D:\\");
RetrieveFile(dir);
```

Comment: non of this worked for me , but the second one I got an error ```if (RetrieveFile(L"D://"))```  ```C++ (const wchar_t [5])L"D://"```

Comment: @JESUSIVANBARRIOSRUBIO: `TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH] = _T("D:\\");
 RetrieveFile(dir);`

Comment: @JESUSIVANBARRIOSRUBIO Fix the 1st method. (sorry for copy-paste the old code of mine.)