# Win32 API : Stack overflow in recursive file search function in C

Tags: c, recursion, winapi

I'm trying to make a program that is supposed to :

- Search for a specific file by going into a directory and its subdirectories (recursively)

But I kinda messed up, I have a stack overflow.
Here's the function that causes me troubles:

```
BOOL LoopThroughDirectories(LPTSTR fileName)
{
    //Searching for files that matches in the current directory
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFirstFile = FindFirstFile(fileName, &ffd);

    if (hFirstFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            //If it's not a directory
            if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)
            {
                _tprintf("%s\n", ffd.cFileName);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFirstFile, &ffd));
    }

    FindClose(hFirstFile);

    //Go into the first unexplored directory
    HANDLE hFirstDir = FindFirstFile(_T("*"), &ffd);

    if (hFirstDir != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            //If it's a directory
            if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                //Go into it 
                SetCurrentDirectory(ffd.cFileName);
                //and do the same
                LoopThroughDirectories(fileName);
                SetCurrentDirectory(_T(".."));
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFirstDir, &ffd));
    }
    FindClose(hFirstDir);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Here's my main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, LPCTSTR argv[])
{
    //Parsing the command line arguments

    //Processing the fileName
    LPTSTR tempPath;
    LPTSTR fileName;

    //Checking for emptyness
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        tempPath = argv[1];
    }

    else
    {
        //If empty set filename to *
        tempPath = _T("*");
    }

    //Removing trailing backslash if any
    LPTSTR backSlash = _tcsrchr(tempPath, _T("\\"));

    if (backSlash != NULL)
    {
        //Replacing backslash with terminating null character
        *backSlash = _T("\0");
    }

    fileName = tempPath;

    //Looping through directories
    LoopThroughDirectories(fileName);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's the exception that the VS Debugger gave me (I speak French sorry):

> Exception non gérée à 0x77382358 (ntdll.dll) dans lsW.exe :
>   0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (paramètres : 0x00000001, 0x00802FEC).

Comment: If a recursive function produces a stack overflow, then the first guess should always be that the recursion is not terminating.

Comment: Your code is far too heavy on WinAPI for me to effectively review it, but one thing to watch out for is recursing into the '.' or '..' subdirectory of any directory.  If your code is in fact doing such a thing consistently then that would definitely produce a non-terminating recursion.

Comment: The point is that already exposed by @JohnBollinger. The logic of your iteration is weak. Don't change the working directory for each new iteration, but modify your function to receive a full path for search file. Using full path in `FindFirstFile()` and filtering for `.` and `..` directories should fix the problem.

Comment: recursion on `.` entry which returned first. if you debug self code - just view this. also you not check for reparse point, `FindFirstFile` very not efficient compare `FindFirstFileEx`, instead use `SetCurrentDirectory` need allocate 64kb buffer at begin and format name here,  if file have `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` yet not mean it not directory. etc

Comment: As @JohnBollinger, you need to skip `.` & `..`, and use `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` to determine whether it is a directory. There is a sample here(Function `RetrieveFile`)https://stackoverflow.com/a/56880186/10611792